# AngularJS - go to next page after key press

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to make it possible for users to go to the next page after pressing the "right arrow". I am able to catch when the right arrow is pressed, but can't find a way to get the "ui-sref" attribute into a variable, which I could then use as a location to navigate to.

This works fine:

```
var handler = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    console.log('right arrow');
  }
};

var $doc = angular.element(document);
$doc.on('keydown', handler);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $doc.off('keydown', handler);
});
```

...but I can't get the attribute of current "next link" using neither jQuery or JQlite. None of the options below do get the attr I need:

```
var elem=  $('.goNextSlide').attr('ui-sref');
var elem=  angular.element('.goNextSlide').attr('ui-sref');
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('.goNextSlide')).attr( 'ui-sref' );
```

What I want to achieve is to get the 'ui-sref' attr on key press and then redirect the location like that:

```
location.href = elem;
```

Any suggestions welcomed :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. What exactly do you mean by " I can't get the attribute of current 'next link'"?

Answer (score 1):

In order to navigate to another page, you have to use `$state.go('state', {params})`.

Check out [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).